# Actions on Google - Suddenly keeps getting into fallback Permission

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

On my device, it remembers that the location permission has been accepted and follow up intents and everything else works. But on the simulator it doesn't want to remember anymore. It keeps saying:

> Sorry, I didn't understand. Right away but first, I need to get your
>   current location from Google. Is that alright?

No matter what if you say yes, no whatever it won't go.
Like it is still in that intent where he is asking for location permission.
This is my webhook and provided some screenshots of the simulator and debug.

```
    app.intent('location_permission_question', (conv) => {
        if (conv.user.storage.currentReservationID) {
            return conv.ask(`No can't do, you have an active reservation.`)
        }

        return conv.ask(new Permission({
            context: `Right away but first`,
            permissions:
                ['DEVICE_PRECISE_LOCATION'],
        }));
    });

    app.intent('handler_permission_location_details', (conv, params, permissionGranted) => {
        if (!permissionGranted) {
            return conv.close(`I can't help you then.`);
        }

        const userLatitude = conv.device.location.coordinates.latitude;
        const userLongitude = conv.device.location.coordinates.longitude;
        conv.user.storage.currentUserLocationLatitude = userLatitude;
        conv.user.storage.currentUserLocationLongitude = userLongitude;

        return clientInitGetNewLocations(conv, userLatitude, userLongitude, false)
    });


    app.intent('choose_car', (conv, {carModel}) => {
        if (!conv.data.cars[carModel]) {
            if (conv.surface.capabilities.has('actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT')) {
                conv.ask(new Suggestions('Next Location'));
            }
            return conv.ask(`I'm sorry but that car model isn't available at ${conv.data.currentLocation.name} you can choose between ${conv.data.carsNames.toString().replaceAll(',', ' and ')}. Which one do you want?`);
        }
        let car = conv.data.cars[carModel][0];
        conv.user.storage.carWaitingForConfirmation = car;
        let carName = car.carModelID.manufacturer;
        const battery = car.batteryChargeLevel;
        const pricePerKM = car.pricing.pricePerKM;
        const pricePerMinDay = car.pricing.pricePerDayMin;
        const pricePerMinNight = car.pricing.pricePerNightMin;

        if (conv.surface.capabilities.has('actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT')) {
            conv.ask(new Suggestions(['Yes', 'No']));
        }
        return conv.ask(`${carName} at ${conv.data.currentLocation.name} has ${battery}% of battery and costs ${pricePerMinDay}€ per minute and ${pricePerKM}€ per kilometer. Is that okay?`);
    }
);
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

**UPDATE #1**
I tested it on real device and there it works normally. It looks like, the problem lies in actions-on-google.

Answer (score 0):

Seems strange that it works on device but not emulator.

But actually, I think that it should rather be the `handler_permission_location_details` intent that declares the event `actions_intent_PERMISSION` in Dialogflow.

I also have an agent that implements location permission to find nearby supermarkets. And this is a short snippet that works. The `Locate supermarkets - Resolve permission` intent is a followup to `Locate supermarkets`.

```
app.intent('Locate supermarkets', conv => {
    conv.ask(new aog.Permission({
        permissions: 'DEVICE_PRECISE_LOCATION',
        context: 'To look for supermarkets near you'
    }));
});

app.intent('Locate supermarkets - Resolve permission', (conv) => {
    if (!!conv.arguments.get('PERMISSION')) {
       // permission granted
    } else {
       // permission NOT granted
    }
});
```

It's the `Locate supermarkets - Resolve permission` that declares the `actions_intent_PERMISSION` event and implements the handler of result

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Excatcly like you said it should work :/, but the problem still persists on the emulator while on the device it works perfectly.

Comment: I feel your pain. I've also experienced times when the emulator didn't behave like the device. It's frustrating, but understandable as it is a young platform. Sumit an issue report if you're confident that it's a bug in the emulator. They're quite responsive. I reported and confirmed a bug some time ago that occured with non-English languages.